# How can I get the video of the camera object in unreal engine5 via UDP?

Tags: unreal-engine5

How can I get the video of the camera object in unreal engine5 via UDP?
I want to get the image of the camera object in unreal engine 5 and transfer it outside the unreal engine. (within the same computer)
In order to do that, I would like to get the image of the camera object in unreal engine 5 with UDP, but how should I do it?